# Delphi: How to make a mouse click counter?

Tags: loops, delphi, counter

I am trying to make a counter that edits the caption of a button according to mouse clicks. I know what the problem is but don't know how to fix it.

Code:

```
procedure TForm1.Shape9MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);

var
icount : integer;

begin
icount := 0;

if button = mbRight then
icount := icount + 1;

button2.caption := 'Count: ' + IntToStr(icount);  

end;
```

Whenever I Right click, the counter is set to 0 + 1 again, when I left click it is set to 0. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: The counter has to be global in scope. Declare it as a private member of TForm1.

Comment: You mean it has to be something other than a Local temporary variable on the stack.  This developer would do well to learn what a local variable is. Also if they want to have a value increase, they would do well not to repeatedly zero it out.  Also learn how to step into your code and step line by line and you will see how this works. good luck learning Balliztica

Answer (score 4):

You've declared your counter as a local variable, which gets reinitialized to zero every time the event handler is called.

You need to make it a form level member variable instead, where it will retain it's value between calls.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  private
    icount: Integer;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Shape9MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if button = mbRight then
    icount := icount + 1;

    button2.caption := 'Count: ' + IntToStr(icount);  
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @Balliztica You do know how to show your appreciation for a correct answer, do you? Click the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.Shape9MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin

if button = mbRight then
button2.Tag := button2.Tag+ 1;

button2.caption := 'Count: ' + IntToStr(button2.Tag);  

end;
```